# Try and find an element in selenium and if its not there refresh until it is [python]

Tags: python, selenium

I currently have the program find the element and click it, but sometimes the element will not be there because the item has not been released yet.  So i would want to the script to check if the item is there and if it is click, if not refresh the page and check again.

### Here is the product finding script:

```
def select_product(keyword, color):
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article//a[contains(., '" + keyword + "')]/../../p/a[contains(., '" + color + "')]").click()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
def select_product(keyword, color):
    xpath = "//article//a[contains(., '" + keyword + "')]/../../p/a[contains(., '" + color + "')]"
    while True:    
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
            return
        except NoSuchElementException:
            sleep(2)
            driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks as stated before im pretty new to python and selenium, just wondering where would i place the click action?

Comment: I ninja edited once or twice or 5 times, it's in there I promise.

Comment: im getting a NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined
any reason why?

Comment: nvm got it had to import from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException